# What are the uses of name element in the tuple of a transformer in sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer?

Tags: data-cleaning

What are the uses of name element in the tuple of a transformer in `sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer`?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, same usecases as pipeline stage names: for example, tuning preprocessing arguments (or even choosing between whole algorithms) along with model hyperparameters with gridsearch-like routines:

```
encoder_list =  [
                    OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore", drop='first'),
                    CatBoostEncoder(),
                ]

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
                    transformers = [
                                        ("encoder", OneHotEncoder(), cat_cols),
                                        ("svd", TruncatedSVD(), cols_to_compress),
                                   ],
                )

pipe = Pipeline([
                    ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                    ('classifier', LogisticRegression()
                ]) 
                
params = {
             'preprocessor__encoder' : encoder_list,
             'preprocessor__svd__n_components': [1, 2],
             'classifier__C' : [0.1, 1., 10],
         }

gcv = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=params, cv=5, scoring='roc_auc')
gcv.fit(X, y)
```